# JQuery validate - too much recursion - stack overflow

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I'm using JQuery validate plug in and getting too much recursion error and have no idea why.

[Here's a fiddle to show the error (you can see it in firebug)](http://jsfiddle.net/agr5jLby/)

To test: enter "john@hotmailcom" in first field, then tab out and see error msg, then click back in and change it to "john@hotmail.com" and tab out again

Here the JQ:

```
  // ensure password contains at least one number and one letter    
  $.validator.addMethod("passwordRegex", function(value, element) {
    return this.optional(element) || /[a-z].*[0-9]|[0-9].*[a-z]/i.test(value);
  }, "Password must contain letters & numbers");

  $("#groupReg").validate({
    errorElement: 'span',
    errorClass: 'field-validation-error2',
        rules: {
            Email: {
                required: true,
                email: true
            },
            EmailConfirm: {
                required: true,
                email: true,
                equalTo: Email
            },
            Password: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 6,
                passwordRegex: "Password format not valid"
            },
        },
        messages: {
            Email: {
                required: "to continue, please enter your email address",
                email: "that's not a valid email address"
      },
            EmailConfirm: {
                required: "to continue, please enter your email address again",
                email: "that's not a valid email address",
                equalTo: "Please ensure the email addresses match"
            },
            Password: {
                required: "to continue, please enter a password using letters and numbers",
                minlength: "Your password must be at least 6 characters long"
            }
        },
    success: function() {           
      $( "#groupReg" ).submit();
    },
    });
```

Any idea what's wrong?

Comment: `Validate` event triggered from `submit` event would be typical. Why are you submitting from the success?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the call to `submit()` from the `success` handler - and possibly the entire `success` handler if that is all you were using it for.

That handler is used when a field is made valid, calling it as you are is ending up in an infinite loop.